# Lookup from one matrix into another as you loop through in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix which I have created which is initially a column vector

```
matrix1 = [1:42]'
```

I have another matrix which is for arguments sake a 2000-by-2 matrix called `matrix2`.
Column 1 of `matrix2` will always be a number between 1 and 42 and is in any order.

I want to loop through `matrix2` column 1  and populate `matrix1` column 2 with the result from `matrix2` column2 against the corresponding number - at the end of each iteration of  the loop I'm going to sum up column2 of matrix2.

so in pseudo code it would be something like this:

```
for i = 1:length(matrix2)
    look at i,1  its a "4" for example - take matrix2 column2
    and populate matrix1 next to the 4
    (ie column 2 in matrix 1 next to the 4 with this number)
```

so matrix 1 initially

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

matrix 2

```
3    100
1    250
2    200
1    80
4    40
5    50
```

so after one iteration matrix1 looks like this

```
1   
2
3   100
4
5
6
```

after iteration 2  matrix1 looks like this

```
1   250
2
3   100
4
5
6
```

after iteration 3 matrix1 looks like this

```
1   250
2   200
3   100
4
5
6
```

As mentioned, I'll perform a calculation after each iteration but the important thing is to populate matrix 1 column2. There will obviously be many over writes or replacements of the numbers in matrix1 column2 but thats fine since im going to perform a calculation after each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for ii =1:length(matrix2)
       matrix1(matrix2(ii,1),2) = matrix2(ii,2);
    end
```

Might need to make matrix1 2D from the start (can just initialize 2nd column to be all 0s).